# What are the differences between Silverlight 2 and Silverlight 3

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-2.0

Can you give me a breakdown of the differences between Silverlight 2 and Silverlight 3?

Comment: Whilst I'm all for programming answers to be found in stackoverflow itself, this really is the sort of thing that can be answered definitively by the people working for the Microsoft with a web search. "whats new Silverlight 3" would seem to be the obvious search and delivers lots of good results.

Comment: I understand what may be new features but I am looking to hear from people who have worked with both as to, what are the real differences, not what's new, more like what has changed etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A guide to Silverlight 3 new features** 
  http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-whats-new-a-guide.aspx

Comment: What is new in Silverlight 3 is, in effect, what is different from version 2.  Few, if any, features were deleted from version 2, and not much has changed, other than adding new features.